# How to find repeating rows and update the first row in the sequence?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to identify repeating rows based on the value of a column and update the "leading" row.

For example, assume I have the following data:

```
Code   Amount
----   ------
ABC     100
DEF     200
HIJ     300
HIJ     170
HIJ     130
```

With the SQL update, the data set should look like this:

```
Code   Amount
----   ------
ABC     100
DEF     200
HIJ     0 (this one is set to 0 based on row number)
HIJ     170
HIJ     130
```

So, find a repeating set within the original dataset based on the `Code` column and update the row that starts the set.

Comment: You are going to need a way to determine 'first' or 'start'

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: First would be the first row of the sequence based on the row number.

Comment: Do you have a row number column? There's no "implicit" row ordering in a table.

Comment: I did not have a row number initially, but it looks like I needed one so I added an ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER/COUNT` windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY id) AS rn
         , COUNT(*)OVER (PARTITION BY Code) AS cnt
  FROM tx
  -- WHERE tx.Code IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET Amount = 0
WHERE rn = 1 AND cnt > 1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/IOUKSB58861)**

You need column to order by like `id/timestamp`

Comment: You can update the `cte` directly and avoid the `join`. http://rextester.com/YLCN50985

Comment: This seems like a quick solution. Needed to put a semicolon before the `with`.

Comment: @lad2025 How would this behave in cases when `code` is null?

Comment: @Mark13426 It will treat all `NULL` as the same group. You could simply exclude them using `WHERE tx.code IS NOT NULL` in subquery

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you had an `id` to use an ordinal:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
      ,rn = row_number() over (partition by code order by id)
  from t
)
update cte
  set Amount = 0
output inserted.code, inserted.amount
from cte 
where rn = 1
  and exists (
    select 1
    from cte i
    where i.code=cte.code
      and i.rn > 1
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PTQ30474

update output:

```
+------+--------+
| code | amount |
+------+--------+
| hij  |      0 |
+------+--------+
```

table after update:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | Code | Amount |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | abc  |    100 |
|  2 | def  |    200 |
|  3 | hij  |      0 |
|  4 | hij  |    170 |
|  5 | hij  |    130 |
+----+------+--------+
```